# I'm having trouble handing over a vector<int> variable in c++ with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am having trouble with handing over a variable as a vector. I hope one of you can help me. The code is supposed to sort the numbers of the vector and I would like to use pointers to prevent copies.

```
vector<int> Heap::heapSort() {
    Heap h;

    vector<int>  heap =  { 5,39,18,0,221,15,99,22,66 };

    cout << "Unsortierte Liste: ";

    for (int h : heap) {
        cout << h << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;


    for (int k = h.parentPos(numHElements); k >= 0; k--) {
        h.bubbleUpMax(heap, k, numHElements);
    }

    while (numHElements > 1) {

        swap(heap[numHElements - 1], heap[0]);

        h.bubbleUpMax(heap, 0, numHElements - 1);

        numHElements--;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////// 

    cout << "Sortierte Liste:   ";
    for (int h : heap) {
        cout << h << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;


    return heap;
}


void Heap::bubbleUpMax(vector<int> * heap, int k, int sizeUnsorted) {
    Heap h;

    while (k * 2 + 1 < sizeUnsorted) {
        // Linke Kindposition: k * 2+1, Rechte Kindposition: k * 2+2 
        int childPos = k * 2 + 1;


        if ((childPos + 1 < sizeUnsorted) && (heap[childPos] < heap[childPos + 1]))
        {
            childPos++;
        }

        if (heap[h.parentPos(childPos)] < heap[childPos]) {  
            swap(heap[childPos], heap[k]);
            k = childPos;
        }

        else {
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use pointers, not references?

Comment: When you do `heap[childPos]` in the sorting function, you treat `heap` as an *array*, where each element is a vector. To get the vector that `heap` is pointing to you need to use the dereference operator `*`, as in `(*heap)[childPos]`. Or use references, as alluded to in a previous comment.

Comment: Replace your `*` with a `&` in the parameter list of `bubbleUpMax`. This will be passing by reference instead of by pointer, which is much more C++-ish. (And then you don't have to worry about taking the address of `heap` or dereferencing the passed-in `heap`)

Comment: *"I am having trouble"* -- could you be more specific? If your trouble involves your computer blowing up, this might not be the best place to seek help (but it would definitely count as "trouble"). Requests for debugging help should be as specific as possible. Ideally they focus on a single issue and include 1) a description of the problem, 2) a [mre], 3) **the actual results** from the example, and 4) (if not a compile-time error or a crash) the desired results. ***Note::** You are close to a [mre], but it cannot be copied and compiled in its current form.*

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! Now it is working with the dereference operator. Thank you @Someprogrammerdude